# Django custom management command error when executed via cron

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cron

I have a custom command that checks an email account and downloads and parses emails. The details about it are not relevant to this problem.

When I run this command from the shell, like:

```
cd /project_dir
./manage.py check_mail
```

It runs fine every time. When the same command is executed via crontab, it returns a weird DB error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac
```

And it returns that exception from different points of the code. Always from (very simple) select queries.

The crontab entry is simple enough:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /project_dir && ./manage.py check_mail
```

And it is run by the same user that I am logged in with for the tests above.

I did find this "SSL error" before with PostgreSQL and Django, when running queries from a subprocess, and I solved it then by closing the connection to force the creation of a new one, like:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.close()
```

But it does not help in this occasion. The postgresql log does not add much information:

```
2013-01-19 16:03:09 GMT LOG:  SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
2013-01-19 16:03:09 GMT LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2013-01-19 16:03:09 GMT LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection
```

I'm using python 2.6 and Django 1.4. This is the (nearly) full traceback of one of those errors, but as I said, it is not always raised from the same query:

```
File "/project_dir/appname/checkmail.py", line 527, in get_message
    message = object.message_set.all().order_by('-time')[0]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]   

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)   

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():   

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):   

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)   

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args) 

django.db.utils.DatabaseError: SSL error: sslv3 alert bad record mac
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: I've just discovered that running the script with `su - user -c "command here"` (where "user" is the same as the owner of the crontab) runs fine. But I would still like to find the source of this error. The differences in the environment variables when running with and without "su - user" do not look relevant to me.

Comment: I think the problem is actually an SSL renegotiation problem.  Check your version of postgresql.  What I'm confused about is why it works in some situations but not in others,  maybe a shared psycopg2 connection pool is being accessed in some situations?

Answer (score 1):

Check that crontab is running the same version of python.  My crontab entries actually look like the following:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /projectdir ; PYTHONPATH=/home/myhome/python/south:/home/myhome/python /usr/local/bin/python2.6 manage.py notify
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I did check the python versions and also the versions of the relevant packages (psycopg2, django, ...), but they are the same.

Answer (score -1):

The default shell used by crontab is likely to be 'sh' instead of bash.  This means the environment it runs in is different that what you normally have at the command line.

Instead of issuing the command directly from cron, try running your management command in a shell script, and then invoking that script from cron.  A working example would look similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /etc/profile

cd /projectdir
./manage.py check_mail
```

If you are using virtualenv, add a line to the script that sources you virtualenv's `activate` command.